# Automount external hard drive on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, mount

I have an external drive plugged in to my MacPro via eSATA. At the moment, the disk only mounts if I log in. Since I am using the computer remotely, this is annoying since I have to open up VNC, log in, and log back out. Is there a way to have external drives automatically mount without user log in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found [a preference](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031103155828117) that might do the trick:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/autodiskmount AutomountDisksWithoutUserLogin true
```

In a variation using a boolean value (which should be more accurate):

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/autodiskmount AutomountDisksWithoutUserLogin -bool true
```

---

You can do the same through Property List editor (if you have it installed):

```
sudo touch /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/autodiskmount.plist
sudo open !$
```

… and set it manually as a boolean:

[image]

<sub>However, and I'm sorry for that, it appears to be older, and I can't try it out, so let me know if it works.</sub>

Comment: After searching around on a solution to fix my wallpaper being reset on each reboot in OS X Mavericks, I only found AppleScript workarounds. Enabling this preference did the trick since it was missing in the `SystemConfiguration` folder and my wallpapers are indeed stored in an external HD. Thanks slhck.